# Add a font awsome icon into php code

Tags: php

I'm using WordPress CMS to develop my website. I need to put a font awesome icon before a heading. See below snapshot for placement.

[image]

This is the current php code:

```
if(empty($search_label)) {
$search_label = 'Search Inventory';}
```

I'm a beginner to PHP so, I appreciate if anyone has a solution to do this easily.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you added font-awesome library?

Comment: pleas also include code snippets for importing the FA library. Also, what did you try already? of-course the code won't show the icon with this line: `$search_label = 'Search Inventory';}`. There's no icon there

Comment: Hi,

I tried the same code provided by Dilip.
$search_label = '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search Inventory';}

Comment: @Nirali I'm using FA icons in my WP site. Do I need to add font-awesome library again to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, include font awesome CSS file in the header.

and then

```
if(empty($search_label)) {
$search_label = '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search Inventory';}
```

Comment: Hi

I tried the same method previously. But the icon isn't visible. 

Now it displaying "<i class="fa fa-search"></i>" before the "Search Inventory" text.

Comment: Still I have the same problem. Now it's appear as follows.
https://prnt.sc/izr1gj

Comment: Please include the font-awesome CSS file in the header.

Comment: Hi Dilip, Thank you for help. I have added the following code in the top of the php file to include CSS file.
 
`<?php echo '<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >'; ?>`

But it also not working for me.

Comment: Hi Dilip, Please find below URL:
 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k8w4UFObxHpkAkdGEATJ-6rIMFifkJTY

Comment: <?php
echo '<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >';
if (empty($search_label)) {
    $search_label = '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>Under Development';
}
echo $search_label;
?>

Comment: I have checked code and that is worked.You try this code.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I just tried the new code. It's working partially. I think css library call is not needed for my site. Icon added without the code. https://prnt.sc/j08ivv
 
See the updated code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vhqQyOmgEfk8dU7jY3o_m0QfgPzZgdDy

FA Icon placed into website. But incorrect placement.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. :)

Comment: Do you have any idea to fix placement issue?

Comment: Can you discuss to chat?

Comment: I haven't tried it. I will ask now. Thanks for help!

Comment: I have not idea placement issue you briefly explain it?

Comment: I added a Unicode character () for it. Thank you for support

Comment: Ok, that is also fine. :)